# Conexão PHP PDO com variável estática em classe

Tags: php, pdo

Fiz uma pesquisa sobre conexões usando singleton no PDO, na maioria o pessoal usa um construct privado ou protegido para que caso não exista a conexão a mesma seja criada ao instanciar um new Classe(), porém escrevi o trecho de código usando funções estáticas e uma variável estática (que recebe a conexão) na classe apresentada abaixo, e pelos meus testes funciona tranquilamente sem recriar várias conexões, no entanto não tenho total certeza se o código faz o mesmo efeito de um singleton, se alguém puder dar um feedback sobre o código agradeço!

```
class Conexao {

    private static $conexao = NULL;
    const DB_HOST = "localhost";
    const DB_NAME = "test";
    const DB_USER = "root";
    const DB_PASS = "12345678";

    private static function conectar(){

        if(empty(self::$conexao)){

            try {

                self::$conexao = new PDO('mysql:host='.self::DB_HOST.';dbname='.self::DB_NAME.';charset=utf8', self::DB_USER, self::DB_PASS);
                self::$conexao->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                if(!self::$conexao){

                    echo "Houve um erro ao efetuar a conexão!";
                    return null;
                }

            } catch(PDOException $e){

                echo "Não foi possível efetuar a conexão ao banco de dados! ".$e->getMessage();
            }

        } else if(isset(self::$conexao)){

            //Conexao já existe
        }

        var_dump(self::$conexao);

        echo "<br>";

        return self::$conexao instanceof PDO ? self::$conexao : null;
    }

    public static function QFA($q, $i){

        return self::conectar()->query($q)->fetchAll(!$i ? PDO::FETCH_ASSOC : NULL);
    }
}

try {

    $x = Conexao::QFA("SELECT * FROM nomes");
    //print_r($x);

    $y = Conexao::QFA("SELECT * FROM nomes");
    //print_r($y);

} catch(PDOException $e){

    print_r($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Mas essas funções e essa variável estão dentro de uma classe ...

Comment: Editei a pergunta .. =D

Comment: Não faz o mesmo efeito de um Singleton porque uma das premissas do Singleton é o construtor privado. Nada te impede de criar novas instâncias da PDO no seu código. Você só pode usar o padrão Singleton em classes que você mesmo cria. Por isso não dá para transformar a PDO em um Singleton, mas dá para fazer isso com a classe Conexao, por exemplo.

Comment: Correto, concordo com sua explicação em relação ao conceito do Singleton (ao qual se utiliza o construtor privado / protegido que caracteriza o mesmo), porém em caso de uso, ao invés de usar o Singleton na classe, efetuar a conexão como mencionei (no código e explicação), implicaria em algum problema em sua opinião?

Comment: Nesse caso como foi mostrado onde devo encerrar(matar) a conexão PDO? Dentro do método que eu utilizei a conexão ou dentro do metodo conectar()?

Comment: Você pode criar um novo método estático na classe e dentro deste método atribuir a variável estática self::$conexao = null e quando o mesmo for executado a conexão irá receber null e não ficará mais disponível.
Dê uma olhada neste link http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php na seção "Example #3 Closing a connection".